# Magic in htaccess rule performing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, infinite-loop, redirect

I have faced against the magic in rewrite rules.

My htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# Dont loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# If the query has 2 оr more slashes one after another (after domain name, in middle of at the end), than remove duplicates and leave just one slash in group 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$0 [R=302,L]

# If the query matches directory (eg morozov.one/pages or morozov.one or morozov.one/) and where is index.html in this directory, then perform redirect: add /index.html to the end of query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [R=302,L]

# Special code to call inner redirect (dont loop code works if inner redirect has performed). I KNOW THIS RULE IS CRAZY, in real htacces another rule (2 rules) is placed here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1$1 [L]
```

The query is:

**morozov.one**

The result:

**morozov.one/index.html**

This is very strange behaviour.

Logic says:

1. the first pass

The second condition (RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //) has not matched, the third condition has matched and the result must be **morozov.one//index.html** (IT IS TRUE, I checked it: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d and next Cond and next Rule behave SO if they are single in htaccess (DirectorySlash Off and RewriteEngine On))

2. the second pass

Parser sees RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$

Condition matches.
Parser breaks performing any rule.

3. The result is **morozov.one//index.html** (two slashes)

Apache says: ha ha ha

---

Another example:
The query is:

**morozov.one///**

The result:

**morozov.one/index.html**

Apache says: mu ha ha ha

---

Can you explain step by step how my thaccess performs the query?
Why two or more slashes disappear?